# why my google app QUERY formula does not work?

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

This is the original query:

> QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheet_name", "Social media posts!A:AS"),"SELECT Col1, Col14, Col12, Col10, Col23, Col16, Col13, Col37, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col2='instagram'")
> [image]

Output of the original query. Please check column H, which has empty cells.

I was trying to subquery the original query with this formula:

> =QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheet_name", "Social media posts!A:AS"),"SELECT Col1, Col14, Col12, Col10, Col23, Col16, Col13, Col37, Col2, Col3  WHERE Col2='instagram'", 1),"SELECT  Col1, SUM(Col2)/Count(Col10), SUM(Col3)/Count(Col10), SUM(Col4)/Count(Col10), SUM(Col5)/Count(Col10), SUM(Col6)/Count(Col10), SUM(Col7)/Count(Col10) group by Col1")

This formula works. However, when i try to add SUM(Col8)/Count(Col10) before the "group by", it doesnt work. Col8 is H column.
Error message is :

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC

Comment: H is not numeric. So it can't sum. Also, where is Google apps script in this? It's just query formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC error means you are trying to do an arithmetic operations on non-numeric data.

Column H looks blank in your screenshot. Perhaps you can test it when there is real data in there?